# HTML elements do not show in browser unless formatted?

Tags: html, pretty-print

I have a strange problem with HTML created through XSLT transformation:

After transformation, if I open up the results published on a server, parts of the content do not show in the browser.

However, if I open up the file in an editor and just do a "pretty-print" command on it (indenting and formatting the code), and then open it in the browser again, everything shows up just fine(!)

Does anyone know what causes this? Why should the formatting matter at all if the html code is exactly the same?

Here's the code before pretty-printing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="sv-se" xml:lang="sv-se">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="copyright" content="(C) Copyright 2005"/>
<meta name="DC.rights.owner" content="(C) Copyright 2005"/>
<meta name="DC.Type" content="concept"/>
<meta name="DC.Title" content="Principschema"/>
<meta name="description" content="Principschema för ettrörssystem Uponor Push 12/ElPush 12 Ventildel Rumsgivare med kapillärrör Cirkulationspump Avluftningsventil Tillopp till golvvärmeslinga Retur från golvvärmeslinga Retur till ..."/>
<meta name="DC.Relation" scheme="URI" content="../../../golvvarme/topics/Push/c_Push12ElPush12TekniskaData.html"/>
<meta name="DC.Format" content="XHTML"/>
<meta name="DC.Identifier" content="Push12Principschema"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../commonltr.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../assets/webhelp_topic.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../assets/expertinfo.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/webhelp_topic.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/expertinfo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../expertinfo.css"/>
<title>Principschema</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/jquery-1.3.2.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"> </script><script src="../../../assets/svgweb/src/svg.js" data-path="../../../assets/svgweb/src"/><script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/frames_redirect.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var prefix = "index.html";
    var ratingFile = "";
    redirectToToc(window.location.search);
    function highlightSearchTerm(){
        if(parent.termsToHighlight != null){
        // highlight each term in the content view  
          for(i = 0 ; i < parent.termsToHighlight.length ; i++){        
              $('*', window.parent.contentwin.document).highlight(parent.termsToHighlight[i]);
          }
        }
    }
//--></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../../../assets/expertinfo.js"> </script></head>
<body class="fullpage" onload="highlightSearchTerm()" id="Push12Principschema"><a name="Push12Principschema"><!-- --></a>
<table class="nav"><tbody><tr><td><div class="navheader"><span class="frames" onclick="redirectFrames(location.pathname)"/></div></td><td width="50%"><a class="navheader_parent_path" href="../../../reuse/c_TekniskaData.html" title="Tekniska data">Tekniska data</a> / <a class="navheader_parent_path" href="../../../golvvarme/topics/Push/c_Push12ElPush12TekniskaData.html" title="Push 12 och ElPush 12">Push 12 och ElPush 12</a></td></tr></tbody></table>


 <h1 class="title topictitle1">Principschema</h1>


 <div class="body conbody">
  <div class="fig fignone" id="Push12Principschema__fig_ddfc5101-4e11-49a9-85ca-1c4570fda22c"><a name="Push12Principschema__fig_ddfc5101-4e11-49a9-85ca-1c4570fda22c"><!-- --></a><p class="figcap">Bild 1. Principschema för ettrörssystem Uponor Push 12/ElPush 12</p>

   <a name="Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46"><!-- --></a><span class="ie"><object classid="image/svg+xml" class="image" id="Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46_ie" src="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Ettrors.svg"/></span><!--TEST TO SEPARATE OBJECTS...--><span class="nonIe"><object type="image/svg+xml" class="image" id="Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46" data="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Ettrors.svg"/></span>
   <a name="Push12Principschema__ol_33e21827-c7be-4500-a5bc-ac59eac79d4d"><!-- --></a><ol class="ol" id="Push12Principschema__ol_33e21827-c7be-4500-a5bc-ac59eac79d4d">
    <li class="li">Ventildel</li>

    <li class="li">Rumsgivare med kapillärrör</li>

    <li class="li">Cirkulationspump</li>

    <li class="li">Avluftningsventil</li>

    <li class="li">Tillopp till golvvärmeslinga</li>

    <li class="li">Retur från golvvärmeslinga</li>

    <li class="li">Retur till primärvärmekälla</li>

    <li class="li">Tillopp från primärvärmekälla</li>

   </ol>

  </div>

  <div class="fig fignone" id="Push12Principschema__fig_a07ba386-317a-4888-ba0e-c46d3d31d028"><a name="Push12Principschema__fig_a07ba386-317a-4888-ba0e-c46d3d31d028"><!-- --></a><p class="figcap">Bild 2. Principschema för tvårörssystem Uponor Push 12/ElPush 12</p>

   <a name="Push12Principschema__image_b218b001-37b1-46b5-8eba-40ea3d14c61e"><!-- --></a><span class="ie"><object classid="image/svg+xml" class="image" id="Push12Principschema__image_b218b001-37b1-46b5-8eba-40ea3d14c61e_ie" src="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Tvarors_Elpush12rev.svg"/></span><!--TEST TO SEPARATE OBJECTS...--><span class="nonIe"><object type="image/svg+xml" class="image" id="Push12Principschema__image_b218b001-37b1-46b5-8eba-40ea3d14c61e" data="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Tvarors_Elpush12rev.svg"/></span>
   <a name="Push12Principschema__ol_63497606-c191-4337-8ae9-243a34ac12f0"><!-- --></a><ol class="ol" id="Push12Principschema__ol_63497606-c191-4337-8ae9-243a34ac12f0">
    <li class="li">Injusteringsventil för reglering av tryckfall i sekundärkretsen</li>

    <li class="li">Reglerdel (termostatreglage)</li>

    <li class="li">Temperaturjusteringsventil</li>

    <li class="li">Propp R3/8" eller anslutning för kapillärrör</li>

    <li class="li">Termostat för automatik till elpatron</li>

    <li class="li">Säkerhetsventil</li>

   </ol>

  </div>

 </div>

<div class="related-links"/>
<div class="navfooter"><script type="text/javascript"><!--         
    function expand(){
        parent.tocwin.expandToTopic(window.location.href, this.getAttribute('href'));
    }
    var aArray = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i< aArray.length; i++){
      aArray[i].onclick = expand;
    }
//--></script></div>
<div style="font-size: smaller"><p class="svgInfo"><a href="#">Klicka här om vissa bilder inte visas.</a></p><div class="svgText" style="font-style: italic;">SVG-bilder används för att bilder ska kunna förstoras utan kvalitetsförlust. Om du har problem att se dessa bilder beror det antagligen på att du har en äldre
                    version av Internet Explorer. Du kan då lösa det genom något av följande alternativ:
                         <ul><li>Använd en annan webbläsare (Chrome, Firefox eller Safari).</li><li>Uppgradera till Internet Explorer 9 eller senare.</li><li>Om du har Internet Explorer 8, installera Flash 10 eller senare så kommer SVG-bilderna att visas som Flashobjekt istället.</li></ul></div></div></body>
</html>
```

And here is the same code after pretty-printing it, which works fine:

```
    <html lang="sv-se" xml:lang="sv-se" xmlns=
"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Mac OS X (vers 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.6), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
  "text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="copyright" content="(C) Copyright 2005" />
  <meta name="DC.rights.owner" content="(C) Copyright 2005" />
  <meta name="DC.Type" content="concept" />
  <meta name="DC.Title" content="Principschema" />
  <meta name="description" content=
  "Principschema för ettrörssystem Uponor Push 12/ElPush 12 Ventildel Rumsgivare med kapillärrör Cirkulationspump Avluftningsventil Tillopp till golvvärmeslinga Retur från golvvärmeslinga Retur till ..." />
  <meta name="DC.Relation" scheme="URI" content=
  "../../../golvvarme/topics/Push/c_Push12ElPush12TekniskaData.html" />
  <meta name="DC.Format" content="XHTML" />
  <meta name="DC.Identifier" content="Push12Principschema" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
  "../../../commonltr.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
  "../../../assets/webhelp_topic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
  "../../../assets/expertinfo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
  "assets/webhelp_topic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
  "assets/expertinfo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=
  "../../../expertinfo.css" />

  <title>Principschema</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "../../../assets/jquery-1.3.2.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "../../../assets/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="../../../assets/svgweb/src/svg.js" data-path=
  "../../../assets/svgweb/src" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "../../../assets/frames_redirect.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  <!--
    var prefix = "index.html";
    var ratingFile = "";
    redirectToToc(window.location.search);
    function highlightSearchTerm(){
        if(parent.termsToHighlight != null){
        // highlight each term in the content view  
          for(i = 0 ; i < parent.termsToHighlight.length ; i++){        
              $('*', window.parent.contentwin.document).highlight(parent.termsToHighlight[i]);
          }
        }
    }
  //-->
  //]]>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "../../../assets/expertinfo.js">
</script>
</head>

<body class="fullpage" onload="highlightSearchTerm()" id=
"Push12Principschema">
  <a name="Push12Principschema"><!-- --></a>

  <table class="nav">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="navheader"></div>
        </td>

        <td width="50%"><a class="navheader_parent_path" href=
        "../../../reuse/c_TekniskaData.html" title=
        "Tekniska data">Tekniska data</a> / <a class=
        "navheader_parent_path" href=
        "../../../golvvarme/topics/Push/c_Push12ElPush12TekniskaData.html"
        title="Push 12 och ElPush 12">Push 12 och ElPush
        12</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h1 class="title topictitle1">Principschema</h1>

  <div class="body conbody">
    <div class="fig fignone" id=
    "Push12Principschema__fig_ddfc5101-4e11-49a9-85ca-1c4570fda22c">
    <a name=
    "Push12Principschema__fig_ddfc5101-4e11-49a9-85ca-1c4570fda22c">
      <!-- --></a>

      <p class="figcap">Bild 1. Principschema för ettrörssystem
      Uponor Push 12/ElPush 12</p><a name=
      "Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46"><!-- --></a><span class="ie"><object classid="image/svg+xml"
      class="image" id=
      "Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46_ie"
      src="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Ettrors.svg">
        </object></span>
        <!--TEST TO SEPARATE OBJECTS...--><span class=
        "nonIe"><object type="image/svg+xml" class="image" id=
        "Push12Principschema__image_538dabf9-da61-46a1-99c4-863a880aed46"
      data="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Ettrors.svg">
        </object></span> <a name=
        "Push12Principschema__ol_33e21827-c7be-4500-a5bc-ac59eac79d4d">
      <!-- --></a>

      <ol class="ol" id=
      "Push12Principschema__ol_33e21827-c7be-4500-a5bc-ac59eac79d4d">
      <li class="li">Ventildel</li>

        <li class="li">Rumsgivare med kapillärrör</li>

        <li class="li">Cirkulationspump</li>

        <li class="li">Avluftningsventil</li>

        <li class="li">Tillopp till golvvärmeslinga</li>

        <li class="li">Retur från golvvärmeslinga</li>

        <li class="li">Retur till primärvärmekälla</li>

        <li class="li">Tillopp från primärvärmekälla</li>
      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="fig fignone" id=
    "Push12Principschema__fig_a07ba386-317a-4888-ba0e-c46d3d31d028">
    <a name=
    "Push12Principschema__fig_a07ba386-317a-4888-ba0e-c46d3d31d028">
      <!-- --></a>

      <p class="figcap">Bild 2. Principschema för tvårörssystem
      Uponor Push 12/ElPush 12</p><a name=
      "Push12Principschema__image_b218b001-37b1-46b5-8eba-40ea3d14c61e"><!-- --></a><span class="ie"><object classid="image/svg+xml"
      class="image" id=
      "Push12Principschema__image_b218b001-37b1-46b5-8eba-40ea3d14c61e_ie"
      src="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Tvarors_Elpush12rev.svg">
        </object></span>
        <!--TEST TO SEPARATE OBJECTS...--><span class=
        "nonIe"><object type="image/svg+xml" class="image" id=
        "Push12Principschema__image_b218b001-37b1-46b5-8eba-40ea3d14c61e"
      data="/handbok/images/Push12_5039/Tvarors_Elpush12rev.svg">
        </object></span> <a name=
        "Push12Principschema__ol_63497606-c191-4337-8ae9-243a34ac12f0">
      <!-- --></a>

      <ol class="ol" id=
      "Push12Principschema__ol_63497606-c191-4337-8ae9-243a34ac12f0">
      <li class="li">Injusteringsventil för reglering av tryckfall
      i sekundärkretsen</li>

        <li class="li">Reglerdel (termostatreglage)</li>

        <li class="li">Temperaturjusteringsventil</li>

        <li class="li">Propp R3/8" eller anslutning för
        kapillärrör</li>

        <li class="li">Termostat för automatik till elpatron</li>

        <li class="li">Säkerhetsventil</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="related-links"></div>

  <div class="navfooter">
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    <!--         
    function expand(){
        parent.tocwin.expandToTopic(window.location.href, this.getAttribute('href'));
    }
    var aArray = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i< aArray.length; i++){
      aArray[i].onclick = expand;
    }
    //-->
    //]]>
    </script>
  </div>

  <div style="font-size: smaller">
    <p class="svgInfo"><a href="#">Klicka här om vissa bilder inte
    visas.</a></p>

    <div class="svgText" style="font-style: italic;">
      SVG-bilder används för att bilder ska kunna förstoras utan
      kvalitetsförlust. Om du har problem att se dessa bilder beror
      det antagligen på att du har en äldre version av Internet
      Explorer. Du kan då lösa det genom något av följande
      alternativ:

      <ul>
        <li>Använd en annan webbläsare (Chrome, Firefox eller
        Safari).</li>

        <li>Uppgradera till Internet Explorer 9 eller senare.</li>

        <li>Om du har Internet Explorer 8, installera Flash 10
        eller senare så kommer SVG-bilderna att visas som
        Flashobjekt istället.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

I realized that because of the problems clearing the cache (see comment below) I wasn't seeing the correct version. So the conditional comments I was using to show different versions of the SVG objects for different browsers wasn't working at all. What is working is when I pretty-print a page with objects without conditional comments. But then I use jQuery to hide the objects that are not to be used for a certain browser instead of using conditional comments.

I updated the HTML code above. This time I used HTML Tidy to pretty-print the code, but the result is the same whether I use that or just pretty-print in the editor I mentioned, so it's not actually that HTML Tidy corrects any errors (reports no errors, only warnings, and then I set it to indent in the options).

Comment: this calls for an **xml tree diff**.

Comment: I cannot see any such problem with the first version. Which browser were you using?

Comment: Right, sorry, I should have made it clearer that the problem only occurs when published on the server (Linux server)... No idea why. But the pretty-print makes the problem go away on the server as well. But why? It doesn't matter which browser, I see the problem in all browsers.

Comment: FF3 shows everything in both source codes, IE7 doesn't show lists in both source codes unless you delete object tags before the lists.

Comment: @sevenkul: Ok, does this give you a clue to what's going on?

Comment: Also, I am actually having extreme problems with knowing what's what on the server, because even if I clear the cache, it seems pages aren't always updated, so it's hard to know if changes are there or not. Anyone know what you can do about that?

Comment: See update, I had the wrong code in the samples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer elsewhere: the problem was that there were a couple of empty tags without closing tag (or rather closed in one and the same tag). Using these for some reason messed it up. The solution was to include some empty text element in these tags before the transformation (script tag and object tag) and then close it with an end tag. That took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

The odds are that something gets broken in the publishing process, so that the version on the server, and thus what browsers get, is different from the data you have created. This may depend on different character encodings in your authoring environment and the server, or on conversion errors in data transfer, or on differences between line break conventions, or on long lines being broken a wrong way by the transfer software. If you post the URL of a version that does not work, the specific nature of the problem would probably be identifiable.

Comment: Ok, sure. I have published a single page with the non-pretty-printed code on a test server. the url is http://www.devemp.expertinfo.se/handbok/index.html, and then you have to drill down in the TOC to Golvvärme > Tekniska data > Push 12 och Elpush 12 > Principschema. Compare that to the one called also Principschema but under Push 45U och 45U Electronic, which has a pretty-printed version of a similar file. You'll see that the one under Push 12 doesn't show the image, and that there is nesting that shouldn't be there. I probably cannot keep the code very long, but I'll leave it there today.

Comment: To explain the "nesting" bit further: If you look at my sample code posted here at SO, you see that the SVG objects are wrapped in a span element each, and these spans are siblings. But when I look at the non-pretty-printed code in FireBug or web inspector, it seems to be interpreted as nested. The pretty-print makes this problem go away, and the code appears with the spans as siblings in FireBug then.

Comment: Despite the use of frames, the problem page has a URL of its own:
http://www.devemp.expertinfo.se/handbok/golvvarme/topics/Push/c_Push12Principschema.html
When viewed with CSS disabled *or* with JavaScript disabled, it shows the image.
It seems that JavaScript code mysteriously adds `display: none` to an element so that its start tag becomes `<span class="ie" style="display: none;">`. This explains what happens, but I cannot tell what explains this! I don’t see how the prettyprint would affect the JavaScript code to produce this outcome.

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't have anything to do with that. The display none is just there on purpose to show different versions of svg to different browsers (controlled by jQuery). See my answer.